# Showing and sum data on php mysql in 1 table

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with showing total order from db group by product title and how many times the product was ordered. The main problem is the code doesn't show the total ordered on each product, it only say 1 although on 1 product have 2 times ordered.

> Field: id, user, title, telp, add, ordered

Record:
Minimalist house type 80/110 -> 2 record and minimalist house type 100 -> 1 record.

All I want is how to show the data like:

> id | title | ordered
>   1  | Minimalist house Type 80/110 | 2
>   2  | Minimalist house Type 100    | 1

but, the reality is:

> 1 | Minimalist house Type 80/110 | 1
>   2 | Minimalist house Type 100 | 1

Here my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, ordered, sum(ordered) as totalordered FROM ordertbl GROUP BY title order by totalordered DESC");

$i = 1;

while($tampil = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$data[$i]=array('NO'=>$i,'JUDUL'=>$tampil['title'],'DIBELI'=>$tampil['ordered']);

    $i++;
}
```

any help will so helpfull. Thanks

Comment: @NikhilBatra like this sir? 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, count(title), ordered, sum(ordered) as totalordered FROM ordertbl GROUP BY title order by totalordered DESC");
i've tried that but nothing happened

Comment: Try this: SELECT id, title, count(ordered) as ordered, sum(ordered) as totalordered FROM ordertbl GROUP BY title order by totalordered DESC

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, title, count(ordered) as ordered, sum(ordered) as totalordered
FROM ordertbl GROUP BY title order by totalordered DESC
```

Remove the normal ordered column and replace it with `count(ordered)` so that proper count is displayed instead of particular order.